# How can I open a file in subfolder in dired mode fast?

Tags: emacs, dired

In dired mode, how can i open the file fastly in the subfolder? I found that after loading `dired+', the key 'j' is`dired-goto-file'. But I cannot use it in the emacs 24 + Windows 7.

Is there any convenient key to open/find the file in subfolder fast?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I recommend using `isearch` when you're finding something in a buffer, including `dired`. I find that the `incremental search` really help and efficient after I get familiar with it.

You can take a look at [10 Specific Ways to Improve Your Productivity With Emacs](https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/effective-emacs). It's tip 4.

As he said:

**"It's difficult to overemphasize how powerful this technique is, once you've mastered it."**

Answer (score 1):

I think I can understand the question. The platform should not matter.
Pressing `j` provides the current directory string in the mini-buffer,
making it convenient to write a file-name and tab-complete it. When that
file-name is a sub-directory of the dired directory, one can find files
in that sub-directory.

Now, if a file in that sub-directory is selected and you press `RET`,
minibuffer informs that *mark set*, and point stay foot.

I tried `C-x C-SPC` `(pop-global-mark)` to see if I would be jumped to
the file found in another buffer, but not so. The mark was set at point.

So this provides no answer but in best case a clarification of the
original question. I could agree it would be nice to be jumped with point on that file in the sub-directory.

I stumbled into this because I wondered what `j` does in dired mode,
pressing it by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear to me.

1. In Dired (including for [**Dired+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/DiredPlus)), `j` prompts you for a file name and *moves the cursor to that file name* in Dired. Does it not do that for you? You say that you cannot use it in Emacs 24 and Windows 7.  I use it in Emacs 24 and Windows 7 (and with **Dired+**) all the time, with no problem.

   Please provide more info. What happens when you use `j`?. What did you expect to happen, and what really happens?
2. But you speak about "**opening**" the file. That is not what `j` does. It is what `RET` does, when the cursor is on the file name. Does that not work for you?
3. Perhaps you just want to open a file after being prompted for its name? For that, just use `C-x 4 f` or `C-x C-f`.

Not clear. But depending on what you really want, perhaps the answer is here: `j`, `RET`, or `C-x 4 f`.

Answer (score -1):

even though i don't use dired mode,
 
i just tried dired and j and the mini buffer prompts me the file to open. I use [lusty mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/LustyExplorer) for files and buffers. but you can use

```
open-dribble-file
```

to open a file from a location

Comment: `open-dribble-file` has absolutely no relevance to this question, so far as I can tell.